# How to run non const methods on nested objects in Composition /Aggregation pattern in C++?

Tags: c++11

I came to from the C# world and, thanks to the "Properties", I can run a setter method on a nested object without leaking any internals like this:

```
objectA.objectB.objectC.SetSomething();
```

So far, I found that the best analog in C++ is to use getters and get nested object by value or const reference than use setters to set them by value. But this would result in the following code:

```
auto b = objectA().getObjectB();
auto c = b.getObjectC();
c.SetSomething();
b.setObjectC(c);
objectA.setObjectB(b);
```

Not only this is 5 lines instead of one, but it involves multiple copies of the nested objects in `b.setObjectC(c);` and `objectA.setObjectB(b);`

I can let the getters to return a non-const reference of a nested object (or use public variables) and will be able to write in C++:

```
objectA.objectB.objectC.SetSomething();
```

But, instantly I get the ability to set **objectB** without **objectA** knowledge like this:

```
objectA.objectB = b {};
```

And this is unacceptable in aggregation pattern where a parent object initializes the nested object.

Other two approaches I read about:

- Instead of aggregation, use multiple protected inheritances and
  translate needed methods with "using". However, I also read in
  "Google C++ Style Guide" to never use protected inheritance..
- Rewrite all required methods in the parent class manually. But this
  would require for me to write SetSomething() method in both ObjectB
  an **objectA** which, in my opinion, violates "Don't repeat
  yourself".

What am I missing? How can this be done? Could anyone please shed some light.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide both `const` and non-`const` getters? Or, if you happen to use particular nested method quite often, simply provide it in your most-outer class and implement it by calling the inner-object version?

Comment: Just write getters that return non-const references. It's not uncommon to end up writing 2 getters for some members, one returning a const reference (which should be the default) and one returning a non-const reference (sometimes people suffix the name `getFooNC()` to differentiate the two)

Comment: This is whole point... Providing non const getter provides full access to the object. Not only can I call non const methods but I can also replace the object itself. Ex objectA.objectB = new b {}; In aggregation pattern where parent object initializes nested object with some special properties this should not be allowed.

Comment: If `getObjectB()` returns a non-const `b&` reference, then `objectA.getObjectB() = new b {}` won't compile. You would, however, be able to write `objectA.getObjectB().getObjectC().SetSomething()`, Is this not what you want?

Comment: Since `objectA.getObjectB()` reterns a reference to an object it is an lvalue. The `objectA.getObjectB() = b {};` (without new) compiles just fine. It is equivalent to `b& tempB = objectA.getObjectB() ; tempB = b {};`. And in the end I'm able to replace the ObjectB inside ObjectA skipping any type of internal logic.